# What undefined behaviour does this C++ code contain

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote up this code after reading item 11 of Effective C++ ( Third Edition ).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_COLORS 20
class Widget
{
 public:
    Widget ( int seed );
    ~Widget ( );
    Widget& operator=( const Widget& rhs );
    void ToString ( );
 private:

    Widget& SelfAssignmentUnsafe ( const Widget& rhs );
    Widget& SelfAssignmentSafe ( const Widget& rhs );
    Widget& SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe ( const Widget& rhs );
    void MakeDeepCopy ( const Widget& rhs );
    int *colorPallete;
};

void Widget::ToString()
{
 int i = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
 {
 cout << "colorPallete[" << i << "]: " << colorPallete[i] << endl;
 }
}

Widget::Widget ( int seed ):
    colorPallete ( new int[MAX_COLORS])
    {
     int i = 0;
     for ( i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
     {
      colorPallete[i] = seed + i;
     }
    }

Widget& Widget::operator=( const Widget& rhs )
{
//    return SelfAssignmentUnsafe ( rhs );

//    return SelfAssignmentSafe( rhs ); 

    return SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe ( rhs );
}

Widget& Widget::SelfAssignmentUnsafe ( const Widget& rhs )
{
    delete[] colorPallete;
    colorPallete = 0;
    MakeDeepCopy( rhs );
    return *this;
}

Widget& Widget::SelfAssignmentSafe ( const Widget& rhs )
{
    if ( this == &rhs ) return *this;

    delete[] colorPallete;
    colorPallete = 0;
    MakeDeepCopy ( rhs );
    return *this;
}

void Widget::MakeDeepCopy ( const Widget& rhs )
{
    int i = 0;
    colorPallete = new int [MAX_COLORS];
    for ( i = 0;i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
    {
     colorPallete[i] = rhs.colorPallete[i];
    }
}

Widget& Widget::SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe ( const Widget& rhs )
{
    int *origColorPallete = colorPallete;
    MakeDeepCopy ( rhs );
    delete[] origColorPallete;
    origColorPallete = 0;
    return *this;    
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
 delete[] colorPallete;
}    


int main()
{
 Widget b(10);
 Widget a(20);
 b.ToString();
 b = b; 
 cout << endl << "After: " << endl;
 b.ToString();
}
```

The author talks about handling assignment to self in the assignment operator:

```
Widget a(10);
a = a;
```

From the assignment operator for Widget I call *Widget::SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe.*

In *Widget::SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe* the idea is to save the colorPallete pointer in origColorPallete. Then make a deep copy of rhs.colorPallete. When the copy succeeds I delete the original pointer and return reference to self.

The above mechanism is supposed to be self assignment and exception safe.

However, *Widget::SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe* is not able to handle assignment to self properly. The colorPallete array contains junk after self-assignment. Its handling the other cases very well.

Why could this be?

Please help.

[EDIT: After examining all the answers]

Thanks for your answers. I have updated the MakeDeepCopy method and the example's working fine now. Below, I have pasted the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_COLORS 20
class Widget
{
 public:
    Widget ( int seed );
    ~Widget ( );
    Widget& operator=( const Widget& rhs );
    void ToString ( );
 private:
    Widget( Widget& rhs );
    Widget& SelfAssignmentUnsafe ( const Widget& rhs );
    Widget& SelfAssignmentSafe ( const Widget& rhs );
    Widget& SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe ( const Widget& rhs );
    void MakeDeepCopy ( const int* rhs );
    int *colorPallete;
};

void Widget::ToString()
{
 int i = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
 {
 cout << "colorPallete[" << i << "]: " << colorPallete[i] << endl;
 }
}

Widget::Widget ( int seed ):
    colorPallete ( new int[MAX_COLORS])
    {
     int i = 0;
     for ( i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
     {
      colorPallete[i] = seed + i;
     }
    }

Widget& Widget::operator=( const Widget& rhs )
{
//    return SelfAssignmentUnsafe ( rhs );

//    return SelfAssignmentSafe( rhs ); 

    return SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe ( rhs );
}

Widget& Widget::SelfAssignmentUnsafe ( const Widget& rhs )
{
    delete[] colorPallete;
    colorPallete = 0;
    MakeDeepCopy( rhs.colorPallete );
    return *this;
}

Widget& Widget::SelfAssignmentSafe ( const Widget& rhs )
{
    if ( this == &rhs ) return *this;

    delete[] colorPallete;
    colorPallete = 0;
    MakeDeepCopy ( rhs.colorPallete );
    return *this;
}

void Widget::MakeDeepCopy ( const int* rhs )
{
    int i = 0;
    colorPallete = new int [MAX_COLORS];
    for ( i = 0;i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
    {
     colorPallete[i] = rhs[i];
    }
}

Widget& Widget::SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe ( const Widget& rhs )
{
    int *origColorPallete = colorPallete;
    MakeDeepCopy ( rhs.colorPallete );
    delete[] origColorPallete;
    origColorPallete = 0;
    return *this;    
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
 delete[] colorPallete;
}    


int main()
{
 Widget b(10);
 Widget a(20);
 b.ToString();
 b = b; 
 cout << endl << "After: " << endl;
 b.ToString();
}
```

[EDIT: Modified code based on Charles's response ]

The idea is to implement "copy-and-swap" idiom to make code both self assignment and exception safe. Note that copy is implemented only in the copy constructor. If the copy succeeds we swap in the assignment operator.

Another improvement over the previous update is that MakeDeepCopy's interface depended on correct usage. We had to store/delete the colorPallete pointer before calling MakeDeepCopy. No such dependencies exist now.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_COLORS 20
class Widget
{
 public:
    Widget ( int seed );
    ~Widget ( );
    Widget& operator=( const Widget& rhs );
    void ToString ( );
    Widget( const Widget& rhs );
 private:
    int *colorPallete;
};

void Widget::ToString()
{
 int i = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
 {
 cout << "colorPallete[" << i << "]: " << colorPallete[i] << endl;
 }
}

Widget::Widget ( int seed ):
    colorPallete ( new int[MAX_COLORS])
    {
     int i = 0;
     for ( i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
     {
      colorPallete[i] = seed + i;
     }
    }

Widget::Widget( const Widget& rhs ):
    colorPallete( new int[MAX_COLORS] )
{
    std::copy ( rhs.colorPallete, rhs.colorPallete + MAX_COLORS, colorPallete );
}

Widget& Widget::operator=( const Widget& rhs )
{
    Widget tmp(rhs);

    std::swap ( colorPallete, tmp.colorPallete );   

    return *this; 
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
 delete[] colorPallete;
}    


int main()
{
 Widget b(10);
 Widget a(20);
 b.ToString();
 b = b; 
 cout << endl << "After: " << endl;
 b.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 for sample code that actually compiles and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It's spelled "palette": one L, two T's.

Comment: oops! I will forever remain a dyslexic

Answer (score 1):

The junk you're seeing is because the `MakeDeepCopy` function always copies from the `colorPallete` member of `rhs`, instead of the copy you made in `origColorPallete`.

The following modification would fix it:

```
int *Widget::MakeDeepCopy ( const int *rhs )
{
    int i = 0;
    int *colorPallete = new int [MAX_COLORS];
    for ( i = 0;i < MAX_COLORS; i++ )
    {
     colorPallete[i] = rhs[i];
    }
    return colorPallete;
}

Widget& Widget::SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe ( const Widget& rhs )
{
    int *origColorPallete = colorPallete;
    colorPallete = MakeDeepCopy ( origColorPallete );
    delete[] origColorPallete;
    origColorPallete = 0;
    return *this;        
}
```

Actually, with the above modification you may want to rename `MakeDeepCopy` to `CopyColorPalette` or something (particularly if you want to keep the original `MakeDeepCopy` for other purposes).

Comment: But under self assignment both origColorPallete and rhs.colorPallete are the same. Correct?

Comment: @ardsrk: so? A new pallete is built and the older is being deleted, but at the end (besides the fact that pointers to the old pallete are broken) the object still has a valid pallete with the correct colors on it. Inefficient but correct, and correct-ness comes before efficiency.

Comment: Greg, your version doesn't use `rhs` at all.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: You're right. Since the OP figured out the problem anyway, I could say that I left that error in there deliberately to aid in understanding the problem. In reality, I simply made a mistake. :) I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

When you call MakeDeepCopy you always pass in the reference to the object. Hence it again runs as a self-assignment.

You'll be much better off if you check against self-assignment in each public method and only run copying if assignment is called with another object passed.

Comment: It is commonly considered a fragile design if you depend on checking for self-assignment for anything but performance.

Comment: I really don't get how this would account for fragile design. I would make the deep copy methods private and check for self-assignment in all relevant public methods. Concise and clear.

Comment: @dribeas: I wonder why.  It makes no sense to overwrite a piece of paper with the same contents, so why would you do this for objects?

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid a lot of this hassle by simply using a std::vector instead of a dynamically allocated array. Vectors support assignment (including self assignment) so there would be nothing really to do.

Comment: Neil, that I could. I only wanted to know the nuances involved.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are not dealing with the copying on itself.
Therefore, when you are performing a copy on itself, the statement

```
colorPallete = new int [MAX_COLORS];
```

is actually also overwriting the colorPallete of rhs

Answer (score 0):

Sticking out like a sore thumb in your example is the lack of a user-defined copy constructor. As you are providing a user-defined destructor and assignment operator, it's reasonable to reason that you might need a user-defined copy constructor and that is, indeed, the case here. Any explicit or implicit call to the compiler generated copy constructor will lead to undefined behaviour when the last of the original and the copy is destroyed.

You can write a trivial *no-throw* swap function for your class and it's fairly easy to write an *exception neutral* copy constructor. (Actually, I believe that it's trivial to write and reasonably easy to reason that it's exception neutral.) If you implement your assignment operator in terms of these two functions (the copy-and-swap idiom), you should find it a lot easier. In particular, you should find that the need for any checks for self-assignment should go away.

**Edit:**

Since your update you have made the Widget assignment operator exception safe. However, your design depends on the fact that you only have a single operation in the assignment operation that could possibly throw (the allocation of new memory) as the assigment of `int`s cannot throw. In general, if you held an array of objects this would not hold.

I understand that `MakeDeepCopy` is a private function, but even so it has an interface the depends heavily on correct usage. Either the member variable `colorPallete` must be `delete[]`ed and set to 0, or it must be saved to a temporary in the event that the call succeeds so that it can then be `delete[]`ed.

Even if you did not want to make a copy constructor public, I would still use it to implement the assignment operator as it makes the whole code simpler.

E.g.

```
Widget::Widget( const Widget& rhs )
    : colorPallete( new int[MAX_COLORS] )
{
    // OK because assigning ints won't through
    std::copy( rhs.colorPallete, rhs.colorPallete + MAX_COLORS. colorPallete );
}

Widget& Widget::operator=( const Widget& rhs )
{
    // Try allocating a copy, Widget's copy constructor must
    // leak anything if it throws

    Widget tmp( rhs );

    // If that worked, swap with the copy - this can't throw

    std::swap( colorPallete, tmp.colorPallete );

    // Our old internals are now part of tmp so will be
    // deallocated by tmp's destructor
}
```

I've got what's effectively your `MakeDeepCopy` in the copy constructor but without any of the necessary conditions on the calling code because it is a copy constructor and a simple two line assignment operator that is (IMHO) more obviously exception safe.

Note that if you held an array of objects that might throw during assignment, you'd have to do something a bit cleverer to maintain exception safety and transparency. e.g. (and this probably illustrates why using a `std::vector` is a good idea):

```
template< class T  >
class PartialArrayDeleter
{
public:
    PartialArrayDeleter( T* p )
        : p_( p ) {}

    ~PartialArrayDeleter()
    {
        delete[] p_;
    }

    void reset()
    {
        p_ = 0;
    }

private:
    T* p_;
};

Widget::Widget( const Widget& rhs )
    : colorPallete( new Obj[MAX_COLORS] )
{
    PartialArrayDeleter<Obj> del( colorPallete );

    std::copy( rhs.colorPallete, rhs.colorPallete + MAX_COLORS. colorPallete );

    del.reset();
}
```

**Edit 2:**

In case you think it's not relevant to consider objects other than `int` being assigned, then note that if you only consider the class that you have, reallocating is not strictly necessary during assignment. All widgets have the same amount of memory allocated in their constructor. A simple, efficient and exception safe assignment operator would be:

```
Widget& Widget::operator=( const Widget& rhs )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i != MAX_COLORS; ++i )
    {
        colorPallete[i] = rhs.colorPallete[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Self-assignment of `int`s is safe and as previous noted assignment of `int`s is also exception safe. (I'm not 100% sure but I don't think that `std::copy` is technically guaranteed safe for a self-assignment copy.)

Comment: Charles, I don't think a copy constructor is needed in this example. I declared the copy constructor to be private and did not provide a definition. Yet the code compiled.

The intention was to implement the copy-and-swap idiom in Widget::SelfAssignmentAndExceptionSafe

Comment: OK, but your posted code doesn't contain a privately declared copy constructor so - as written - your posted Wibble is not robust even if it doesn't affect the example main usage. The advantage of a copy constructor is that you are guaranteed to be working with a brand new object. This means that you don't have to worry about what the 'old' state of the object is. You are going to come across the sort of complications that you have if you try and implement the 'copy' part of 'copy and swap' anywhere other than in a copy constructor.